# Android Libraries and Expansion apks

Tags: android

Im developing an app which has feature that requires a library that increases the apk size in 10MB... (libs and assets files)

Not all users will be interested in this feature so I want it to be there only for those who really want it.

I've been reading about expansion apk but I think it will only solve the problem for the assets files (5MB which is not bad).

So there are only 5MB left that is the libs sizes. I think libraries are linked (or whatever ) during compiling... but maybe someone knows a workaround for this...

The question:

Is it possible to release the application without the library and, only if the user wants to use that feature, download the library from my server and use it in the app later?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DexClassLoader to load the classes not installed part of your application.

Please refer to this documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html